# adjusting bottomsheet in flutter

Tags: flutter, bottom-sheet

I have a bottom sheet in my app, which is appears correctly for the phone with 5 + size, but when I run on the smaller screen phones I am getting like below

[image]

the issue is with the padding as it crosses the range, is there any alternative way for creating bottomsheet and also its contents size should be specific to the device? how to auto adjust the font size,also padding based on the device specific.

below is the code for the same

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        context: context,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return FractionallySizedBox(
              heightFactor: 0.2,
              child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 22.0,
                    vertical: 14.0,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                          title: Text(
                            "View",
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                            maxLines: 1,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize:
                                  ScreenUtil(allowFontScaling: true).setSp(50),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            setGenerateReportView(context, count, data);
                          }),
                      ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.file_download),
                          title: Text(
                            "Download",
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                            maxLines: 1,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize:
                                  ScreenUtil(allowFontScaling: true).setSp(50),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onTap: () => {
                                Toast.show("Downloading", context,
                                    duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG,
                                    gravity: Toast.BOTTOM),
                                Navigator.of(context).pop()
                              }),
                    ],
                  )));
        });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Column` widget by default expands to the maximum vertical space. So instead of using `Column`, use [`Wrap`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) widget which adjusts its children according to the space on screen. Working code below on emulator of screen size < 5 and > 5 respectively:

```
child:
                  Wrap(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                          leading: Icon(Icons.remove_red_eye),
                          title: Text(
                                      ....
```

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 7):

First use this attribute for your column:

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  child: ...
)
```

Also try to wrap your content with **LayoutBuilder** widget to have access to constraints of **BottomSheet** size, so you can set size of the widgets based on the space you have.

[*Flutter LayoutBuilder*](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html)